# Three js не изменяется геометрия меша при повороте

Tags: javascript, математика, three.js

При повороте меша, не изменяется его геометрия
В результате чего, raycaster видит неправильную геометрию
Будто поворота не было. Пробовал mesh.rotation.y
геометрия куба на сцене также не изменяется

```
mesh = new THREE.Mesh( new THREE.BoxGeometry( 1, 1, 1 ), material );
mesh.rotateY(PI_2/2);
scene.add( mesh );
```

В результате чего, нормали на сцене не повёрнуты
[image: Нормали не повёрнуты]

Вот сам куб: 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужна функция какая-нибудь изменяющая поворот
Знаю что это делается с помощью матриц, но в матрицах не шарю
Вот отрывок кода raycaster:

```
raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();
raycaster.near = 0.01;
raycaster.far = 10;
raycaster.set(
    new THREE.Vector3(
        camera.position.x,
        camera.position.y,
        camera.position.z
        ),
        resultVector
    );
    var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects( scene.children,true );
    if(intersects[0] !== undefined && intersects[0] !== null){
        console.log(intersects[0]);
        if(intersects[0].distance < 0.5){
            normalX = intersects[0].face.normal.x;
            normalY = intersects[0].face.normal.y;
            normalZ = intersects[0].face.normal.z;
            directVector = resultVector.projectOnPlane(new THREE.Vector3(normalX, normalY, normalZ));
        }
    }
```

resultVector - вектор направления движения без препятствий

Нужна матричная функция поворота геометрии меша

Буду благодарен...

Comment: А чего вы пытаетесь долбится таким образом?)

Comment: @StrangerintheQ чтобы камера видела повернутые препятствия

Answer (score 1):

Решил проблему. Нужно было геометрию развернуть geometry.rotateY(angle)

Comment: А такой разворот - он происходит единожды при создании сцены? Или бокс постоянно вращается?

Comment: @prisoner849 мне нужно было единожды